# Receive data from Django front end form

Tags: django, forms, post

what I am trying to do:

I am trying to get data from Django frontend table, and post it back to frontend.
 I am not using modelForm, I thought I don't need save the data to database.

My code:

in views.py:

```
def panelThree(request):

    startDate = ''
    endDate = ''
    byOtherField = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QueryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            startDate = request.POST.get('date')
            endDate = request.POST.get('date1')
            byOtherField = request.POST.get('date2')

    else:
        form = QueryForm()

    # if not byOtherField:
    dataTable = Production.objects.order_by('-id')
    return render(request, 'frontend/panelThree.html', {
        'form': form, 'dataTable': dataTable,  'startDate':startDate
    })
```

frontend_form:

```
<form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label >
                       TextField1
                      </label>
                      <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
                      <p> >> Start Date </p>
                    </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label " for="date1">
                         TextField2
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="date1" name="date1" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
                        <p> >> End Date </p>
                   </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   <label class="control-label " >
                    Or
                   </label>
                  <label class="control-label " for="date2">
                   TextField3
                  </label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="date2" name="date2" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
                  <p> >> By Other Field </p>
                 </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
                 <div class="button-box">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit"> Search </button>
                </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

My error:

there is no error, but I just cannot get value from the form post to 'startDate'. It always shows blank value.

I appreciate the help to address this issue, or any ways to work around. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the "if form.is_valid()" statement, and changing back to request.POST.get method,  it's working

```
def panelThree(request):

        startDate = ''
        endDate = ''
        byOtherField = ''

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = QueryForm(request.POST)

            startDate = request.POST.get('startDate')
            endDate = request.POST.get('endDate')
            byOtherField = request.POST.get('byOtherField')

        else:
            form = QueryForm()

        # if not byOtherField:
        dataTable = Production.objects.order_by('-id')
        return render(request, 'frontend/panelThree.html', {
            'form': form, 'dataTable': dataTable,  'startDate':startDate
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems here.

### 1) The fields in the html are named incorrectly.

```
<input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
```

The `name` field here should be set to `startDate`, and so should the `id` field.

### 2) You're grabbing data directly from POST.

After verifying the form `is_valid`, you should get data from it like this:

```
startDate = form.cleaned_data['startDate']
```

Comment: Dear Thomas, first,  thank you very much for you help!  I tried your suggestion, it still does not work,  I think the posted value from the form is not passed to the "startDate" variable,  because I assigned blank (' ') to startDate at the beginning of the function, but if I changed to 'None', it will be rendered as None on the frontend side. But if I don't initiate the variables first , I will get an error message " local variable 'startDate' referenced before assignment".   Do you have any suggestion on this?